# Evenly distribute li items, with absolute width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

In the footer of a responsive website, I need to evenly distribute some li items.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

And this is what I have:

[image]

I would like to avoid setting absolute width for each li, to keep a responsive capability of this part of the website.

What would be the optimal way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
text-align:justify;
```

for your ul element

here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/833/

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain your use of "before" and "after"?

Answer (score 1):

The effect in your screenshot can be achieved by using a margin:

```
.bottomMenu li {
    margin-right: 24px;
}
```

If you want a nice, justified look and you are not concerned with very old browsers, you can use a flex model:

```
.bottomMenu (
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I would like to avoid using absolute values for width (px) and rather go with relative ones (%). I have implemented the second part of your recommendation but did not achieved the expected result. Here is a link to the website: www.guestbud.com/secret. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your `footermenu` div includes only one child (`ul`), so there is nothing to space. You need to set these rules (`display:flex;justify-content:space-between;`) on `.footermenu ul`. Also, you have one empty `li` element there which interferes with the spacing.